# neo4j offline rpm aren't signed

Tags: neo4j, rpm

We are in the process of installing a 4.x version of Neo4j community on an offline server.
We followed https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/rpm/#linux-rpm-install-offline-install-download

The packages served by https://dist.neo4j.org/rpm/ doesn't seem to be signed.

Is that normal?? This seems dangerous for a product like this (I tested several versions, including lastest enterprise)

```
rpm -qip neo4j-enterprise-5.3.0-1.noarch.rpm
Name        : neo4j-enterprise
Version     : 5.3.0
Release     : 1
Architecture: noarch
Install Date: (not installed)
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 226422290
License     : Proprietary
Signature   : (none)
Source RPM  : neo4j-enterprise-5.3.0-1.src.rpm
Build Date  : Thu Dec 15 14:35:50 2022
Build Host  : 385d2a9db634
Relocations : (not relocatable)
URL         : http://neo4j.com/
Summary     : Neo4j server is a database that stores data as graphs rather than tables.
Description :

Neo4j is a highly scalable, native graph database purpose-built to
leverage not only data but also its relationships.
```

- downloaded via `curl -O https://dist.neo4j.org/rpm/neo4j-enterprise-5.3.0-1.noarch.rpm` then checked the package with `curl -O https://dist.neo4j.org/rpm/neo4j-enterprise-5.3.0-1.noarch.rpm`
- expected a signed package
- got an unsigned package

Comment: You can ask neo4j directly, say [here](https://discourse.neo4j.com/c/neo4j-graph-platform/installation).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the provider and you if you think it is dangerous. The package does not need to be signed when you build or install it. It actually requires additional effort to sign it.

When the package is not signed, then you can be attacked using a man-in-the-middle attack.

It is the same as when you browse the web using HTTP vs. HTTPS.

I would be ok install not signed package to the developer ephemeral VM. I require signed packages for production machines.

You should ask Neo4j to sign the packages.